# bitbucket private repository on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, bitbucket

I have a rails app which requires a gem. I host this gem on bitbucket in a private repository.

In my Gemfile I added the gem like following:

```
gem "my-gem", :git => "git@bitbucket.org:my-username/my-gem.git", :branch => 'master'
```

I want to deploy my rails app on heroku with

```
git push heroku master
```

Now I always get following error

```
Fetching git@bitbucket.org:my-username/my-git-repo.git
Host key verification failed.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I understand the error, because the repository is set to private. But how can I solve this problem?

I already read this question: [Deploying to Heroku using git on bitbucket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13240227/deploying-to-heroku-using-git-on-bitbucket), but I don´t really get the answer :)..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Bitbucket allows for HTTP basic auth on repository URLs similar to github. Specify the URL for the gem as `https://username:password@bitbucket.org/username/gemrepo.git`.

It *does* mean having your username and password in your Gemfile, which itself is version controlled, and that's not a good practice, but on the other hand that's what Heroku recommends, so...

Comment: I just tried it. I created a bitbucket account and a dummy repositry, and was able to clone using `git clone https://nitzanshaked:mypassword@bitbucket.org/nitzanshaked/test-repo.git`.I assume that if you use that as the URL for your gem it should work. Note that I used 'https://', not 'git+https://'.

Comment: Ok I tried it with "git" instead of "https". Thank you very much! Works perfect! But I don´t like to put the password into the Gemfile, but anyway, thanks for your reply.

Comment: To avoid security issues associated with storing YOUR bitbucket password in Gemfile, just create a new user and grant it read access to that private gem repository. See [this post](http://www.itsudo.com/gems/2013/10/20/private-gems-on-bitbucket.html) for details.

Answer (score 8):

The proper way to achieve this is [using bundle config](http://bundler.io/man/bundle-config.1.html), which saves the configuration on your home directory `.bundle/config` so it stays outside the repo.

`bundle config bitbucket.org user:pwd`

And then on Heroku you have to set a [simple configuration in a special way](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bundler-configuration):

`heroku config:set BUNDLE_BITBUCKET__ORG=user:pwd`

And in your Gemfile you just use the URL without the credentials.

`gem 'gemname', git: "https://bitbucket.org/User/gemname.git"`

Comment: Thats really simple and clearest way to achieve what we need. Thanks!

Comment: This definitely looks like the way to go with Heroku deployments. Thanks!

Comment: Finally, a working answer.  The key is not to use the bundler "bitbucket:" method, which seems to only work on public repos.   But I had to include the whole url in the config command: bundler config "https://bitbucket.org/User/mygem.git" user:password

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem, but I ended up doing the following as a workaround to providing the Bitbucket password in the `Gemfile`.

The basic idea is to clone the gem from Bitbucket into a local directory, add it to your app and package it into `vendor/cache` so Heroku can use it. My exact steps are below:

1. Clone your gem to a local directory:

   `git clone git@bitbucket.org:me/my_private_gem.git /home/me/my_private_gem`
2. Add the gem to your `Gemfile` as a 'fake' Bitbucket repo:

   `gem 'my_private_gem', :git => 'git@bitbucket.org:me/my_private_gem.git', :branch => 'master' # this repo will not be used`
3. Configure Bundler to work against the local repository (where you cloned the gem in step 1):

   `bundle config local.my_private_gem /home/me/my_private_gem`
4. Run `bundle install` as usual, you should see something like this:

   > Using my_private_gem (0.0.1) from git@bitbucket.org:me/my_private_gem.git (at /home/me/my_private_gem)
5. Package all your gems into `/vendor`

   `bundle package --all`
6. Add `/vendor` to your repo

   `git add vendor && git commit -m 'add my_private_gem to /vendor/cache'`
7. Push to Heroku (don't forget to commit your updated `Gemfile` and `Gemfile.lock` first), you should see something like the following:

   > Using my_private_gem (0.0.1) from git://github.com/my_private_gem/my_private_gem.git (at /tmp/build_19fmj3tup0zy2/vendor/cache/my_private_gem-8bc6f436e2c8)

References:

- [Bundler - Local Git Repos](http://bundler.io/v1.3/git.html)
- [Bundler - package](http://bundler.io/v1.3/bundle_package.html)

Comment: This worked for me.  But after updating the gem locally, rather than doing `bundle install` to update, I needed to do `bundle install --local`. This is mentioned in the referenced [Bundler - package](http://bundler.io/v1.3/bundle_package.html).

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to use ENV vars instead of a new user like:

`https://#{ENV['BITBUCKET_USER']}:#{ENV['BITBUCKET_PWD']}....`

Then set them using:

`heroku config:add BITBUCKET_X=value`

For your development environment you can use the dotenv gem to define the credentials.

See also: [How can I specify a gem to pull from a private github repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4840680/how-can-i-specify-a-gem-to-pull-from-a-private-github-repository)