# Deploying applications

Tags: node.js, git, express, heroku, bitbucket

I want to deploy my express nodejs app stored in a private Bitbucket repository to heroku. I have already pushed the code to the bitbucket private repo.

I have searched in the heroku interface for the bitbucket connection option that would let me automatically deploy the pushed code, however I could only find Github connection option.

I am newbie in web dev, so this question might be very primitive.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deploying to Heroku using git on bitbucket](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13240227/deploying-to-heroku-using-git-on-bitbucket)

Answer (score 0):

Why not only push to heroku, here is what I'm doing in CMD.

```
git add .
git commit -m -a
heroku login
heroku create
git push heroku master
```

More [detail](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-nodejs)

Even [more](http://blog.codeship.com/heroku-bitbucket-nodejs-deployment/)

Comment: you may need to add remote if you don't want to create new app.