# Deploy MERN App to Heroku from BitBucket CI/CD

Tags: reactjs, heroku, server, build-automation, bitbucket-pipelines

My folder structure is

- client (React)
- server (Express)
- .gitignore
- bitbucket-pipelines.yml
- README.md

How to define my **package.json** and **bitbucket-pipelines.yml** for deploying it to **BitBucket Pipeline** and then to **Heroku**?

Comment: check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13240227/deploying-to-heroku-using-git-on-bitbucket

Comment: But in this, there's no mention of how to write my files for my project structure!!